# Google-Apps-Script editor not suggesting function? (auto completion)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

Sometimes when I'm writing a script in google docs, the environment just stops suggesting functions when I type a ".".  Any one know what this might happen? I can not pinpoint anything I am doing to cause it, and can not replicate the problem, it just happens randomly.

Comment: internet connection? may be

Comment: @JuliandotNut Not internet connection, if I try something like `UiApp.` it will suggest something, but with variables I have declared, it stops randomly.  Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens sometimes when you try to save a version with a syntax error but also for no apparent reason. I remember the subject has been discussed on SO already and that a few people commented on this but I just can't remember when nor find the related post. Anyway, there is no really efficient way to make it work again...

When it happens to me I usually create a new project and copy/paste the code in it... not very smart but at least it works.

I'd be glad if someone could suggest an better way to fix it or knows the exact origin so I could avoid to let it happen (since I use A LOT the autocompletion feature :-).

*PS : this is not really an answer, I know but it was definitely to long to fit in a comment.*

Comment: Haha, I will accept it as an answer simply because I know now that it is not just my computer =P.  Thanks again Serge!

Comment: Thanks, And maybe this thread will get attention from someone who KNOWS :-)